# Not able to push logs using pushgateway in nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is the code for pushgateway. I am able to send metrics using Curl but it is creating an error
code:

```
var client = require('prom-client');
var gateway = new client.Pushgateway("http://localhost:9091");

gateway.pushAdd({ jobName: 'try123' }, function(err, resp, body) {

    console.log(err, JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log(resp);
    //console.log("BODY");
    console.log(body , JSON.stringify(body));
});
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: What is the error? please provide us with more information

Comment: Error is null and it is giving an Incoming message which contains each and every single detail.

Comment: Could you add the details in your answer? also the `curl` request?

Comment: This is the curl command       echo "test 60" | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/task

Comment: found an answer?